# How to do the parallax effect similar to tokiolab.it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I have been reading a lot about jQuery parallax and I just don't get it at all. I want to do the same as this site:

http://www.tokiolab.it/#/

As you can see the first page is an animation which is really easy but when you scroll the next page starts covering part of the first one. Can someone help me a bit, I know you need to use z-index but how do you achieve that effect - it seems to not be that difficult, maybe a fixed background or a fixed div, any ideas?

Thanks alot! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at page source or read a tutorial!