# Parallax effect on header portion

Tags: html, css, background, scroll, parallax

Is there any easy solutions to get parallax effect up and running really easy?

I just want a simple and neat effect on my header. This is my page: www.arcanova.no/bolig
I want the header text "Bolig" to scroll faster than the picture behind it.

Here is my html code:

```
    <section class="band banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columns sixteen">
                    <div class="duk"><p></p> </div>
                    <div class="overskrift_firma">
                    <h2>Bolig</h2>
                    </div>  
                </div> <!--/columns sixteen banner-->
            </div><!--/ row-->
        </div> <!-- / container-->
</section> <!-- / band -->
```

The picture is the background of the band banner section class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do the parallax effect similar to tokiolab.it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143340/how-to-do-the-parallax-effect-similar-to-tokiolab-it)

Comment: I will try to make a fiddle.Check for an answer later

Answer (score 0):

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/dMLES/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#back').css({'top':''+(-($(this).scrollTop()*0.05))+'px'});
});
```

Hope from above you will get an idea of how parallax works

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I still cant figure it out. I am a complete newbie at jquery.

The only thing that I need is to slow down the scrolling speed of the background picture behind the "bolig" text.

Is that possible with just some simple code?

Comment: I have provided a simple code.Do you want the entire script of the fiddle i created.Just play with the code and slowly you will learn