# How to create a webpage with Parallax background video

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, parallax

Have been searching for parallax video  for days but I couldnt found out any tutorial how to do it..

All I found is just parallax for background image, not for video..

Can anybody tell or guide me how to do it?

Really appreciate the help . :)

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for http://www.kriesi.at/archives/enfold-version-2-5-fullscreen-video-video-section-parallax-backgrounds-and-more AND http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/how-to-add-full-screen-video-background-to-postpage-without-plugin

found them on a quick Google, but was able to understand the basics.

personally, whenever I have to emulate such a common behaviour, I use a template as a guideline, trying to replicate it myself by taking parts of code, gluing them together in order to achieve the purpose. most of the times, it works :)

Comment: hello do you know how to add a video into a div background? thanks

Comment: try using this tutorial for youself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143340/how-to-do-the-parallax-effect-similar-to-tokiolab-it?rq=1